# Internal Ethernet adapter not detected on Macbook 4.1 running 10.7.5, it works fine on Linux Mint

Tags: macbook-pro, ethernet, driver

I have a dual boot MacBook 4.1 running Mac OSX Lion and Linux Mint 20.3.
In Mac OSX, the ethernet adapter doesn't work and I get a message "This computer does not appear to have any PCI Ethernet cards installed." on the system profiler.

When I boot into Linux, the ethernet connection is detected and works fine.

What can I do to persuade Mac OSX to detect the ethernet adapter?